# Pixel Editor in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.8.3 to edit pixels in a thematic classified raster using the Reclass Using Features function in Pixel Editor. It takes a polygon from a feature dataset in my map and assigns its code to the pixels inside it. But the tool also creates NO DATA areas outside the polygon. How do I correct this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. As currently written, your Question's only question is a discussion invitation. Please [Edit] the Question so it can be answered.

Comment: I just tried the pixel editor and used a polygon in a layer to recode pixels and it worked correctly. Please edit your question to show the data you have used as well as which tools you have used.